# React-Native Error: Connection to http://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy?role=client timed out

Tags: react-native

I run `react-native run-ios` command and my app show for 3 secs before showing this. I am running on ios simulator

[image]

> ExceptionsManager.js:76 Connection to
>   http://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy?role=client timed out. Are you
>   running node proxy? If you are running on the device, check if you
>   have the right IP address in `RCTWebSocketExecutor.m`.

Comment: What happens when you visit, http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui ?

Comment: React Native JS code runs inside this Chrome tab.

Press ⌘⌥J to open Developer Tools. Enable Pause On Caught Exceptions for a better debugging experience.

Status: Waiting, press ⌘R in simulator to reload and connect.

Comment: the above is what i got

Comment: try visiting  localhost:8081/debugger-ui  in your browser?

Comment: this happened again and when this happen 2 react native debugger appear on google chrome. Status: Another debugger is already connected

Comment: If you see this error on a mobile device, shake the device and disable remote debugging!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I somehow managed to make it work without creating a new project by deleting the project app in the simulator on the iOS home screen. It works fine now.

Comment: I'm using expo, and I needed to delete the "ios" and "Expo" apps to get it to work

Comment: I thought this worked at first but it turns out it's just because installing fresh had disabled the "Debug Remote JS" option and it was no longer trying to connect to the debugger.

Comment: @KevinCooper Did you find another way to fix the issue? I tried to delete the project app but I still have the same issue too.

Comment: @jitowix no, this still happens occasionally for me (always about 5 seconds after running the app) and I've found no way around it. I just reload the app whenever it happens and then it's fine for a while.

Comment: @KevinCooper Ok... My app also crashes every ~2-10 mins when Remote Js Debugging is enabled. (don't know why, maybe because of Realm) This makes RN dev a nightmare.

Answer (score 43):

For remote debugging, Your both devices must be connected to the same wifi ( network ).

Comment: This worked for me!  iPad was still on airplane mode from an earlier test.

Comment: I had my wifi turned off. I can't believe I had to look this up to figure that out.

Comment: Mark me as one who faced the issue due to this reason

Comment: I'm thinking the same as @Sean.  imo errors like this should always have a list of probable causes (which I've actually seen with other errors in RN but not this one for some reason)

Answer (score 32):

I get this issue often. Usually when I'm developing with the remote debugger on and I save codebreaking kind of error.

Try to reload... If that doesn't fix it:
crlt + cmd + z. then stop remote debugging, then refresh. That will fix it but now you lost your debugger. So go again...
crlt + cmd + z. this time start remote debugging, then refresh again. Your project should be back and good to go.

This works for me, but it's super annoying and time-consuming. I wish someone had a better way.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! @phongyewtong - I think you should accept this answer instead of your own.

Comment: Has anyone found an alternative to Expo XDE? Their stuff doesn't seem to be functioning properly yet (even some of the view components), and it's become a huge time drain.

Comment: I noticed that it happens every time when I have my iPhone with Personal Hotspot enabled plugged in, and, at the same time, connect to some wi-fi network on Mac. Seems react-native cannot choose which IP to use to talk to Mac. Disabling Personal Hotspot or disconnecting from wi-fi helps.

Answer (score 12):

This seemingly was happening to me because I had restarted the react-native packager while I still had a Chrome debugger open which was attached to the previous packager/emulator instance.

Killing that debugger Chrome tab and trying `run-ios` again seemed to solve it, without any restarts or other skulduggery.

Answer (score 12):

**Update for iOS 14:**

[image]

(image from https://www.iphonetricks.org/ios-14-local-network-privacy-feature/)

On iOS 14, when you launch your app on first time, iOS will ask for your permission to scan local network. You need to allow otherwise the app will not be able to connect to remote debugger on your Mac.

Answer (score 8):

For me this happened when I was try to debug a real device. Issue was that my computer and my real device were not on the same WiFi.

Answer (score 5):

Problem can be with your router. Try connect to wifi through iPhone hotspot.

[On github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14288) I found workaround, how to set DNS to solving this error on your mac and iPhone:

1. On you dev machine, System Preference -> Network -> Wi-Fi ->
   adcanced    -> nameOfYourNetwork
2. In the DNS tab change the ip to 8.8.8.8
3. Make the same DNS change on your iPhone

Comment: This is what the [official documentation suggests](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#troubleshooting): _React Native uses the wildcard DNS service xip.io to address your device. Some routers have security features to prevent DNS Servers to resolve anything in the local IP range._

This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error when I forgot to switch back to using index file instead of jsbundle after release build.

I had

`jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];`

Instead of

`jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];`

Switched to index file and built again and it worked.

Comment: You saved my bacon with this comment.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

For me this works:

- Stop remote js debugging.
- Close remote js debugger page on brower.
- Run React Native Debugger.
- Press `ctrl+t` and type `React Native pakager port` and confirm.
- On simulator press `ctrl+M` and active remote js debugging.

and good to go!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was on a different network than the phone. No SIM Card required, I only needed to make sure I was on the same network (we have work and guest networks here). There are some notes in the documentation for RN that you can checkout (mid-way down there is a pink box with the proxy issue we have all faced):

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

Answer (score 2):

I fixed adding a script in "bundle react native code and images" build phases tab main target. I simply added `export DISABLE_XIP=NOTHANKS`

[image]

The problem was that real device was trying to connect to my ip under xip.io domain

I think this script it is necessary when we are going to add custom images assets in the xCode project, but you can check the url of the ip is wrong in Report navigator tab.
[image]

My setup

`react: 16.3.1,
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.55.4
xCode 9.4.1`

Here the original react native docs about xip.io (Troubleshooting chapter)
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device

Here the possibility for disable XIP.
https://github.com/facebook/metro/commit/079dcaed990abb6754c03113362e4f537cd32a24

Here the hint that I found for trying this solution
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12786

Comment: thanks, this worked for me, not sure why this doesn't have more votes

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot and finally fixed it by adding `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to info.plist.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get:

> Another Debugger is already connected

It might sound silly, but don't forget to check for Chrome windows in the background, which could be the "another debugger".

When you tap on "Start JS Debugging", React Native opens a new Chrome window with the debugger. If you have multiple Chrome windows (not tabs) open on Mac OS X, you don't see any visual indication that there is more than one window, so you might be looking at the foreground window with "Another debugger is already connected" and don't realize that the other debugger is a Chrome window in the background.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I was connecting via a WiFi network that had a **captive portal** (aka a pop up window that required you to fill some info before connecting to the internet).

*Please make sure you are connecting via a WiFi Network that has no captive portal.*
Even your personal hotspot on your phone will do the trick!

Here is the reference I never read and cost me some hours:

> If you have any issues, ensure that your Mac and device are on the same network and can reach each other. Many open wireless networks with captive portals are configured to prevent devices from reaching other devices on the network. You may use your device's Personal Hotspot feature in this case.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device#troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

Working on mac.
I solved it by enable "Internet Sharing".
- Go to Settings --> Sharing
- Share you connection from "USB 10/100/1000 LAN"
- To computer using: "Wi-fi"
- check "Internet Sharing" --> create your network
- in your iPhone connect to the new network
- Reload metro and xcode

Comment: I was working out of a Starbucks (public internet) and this worked for me (MAke sure to turn off the Wifi if you enable this)

Comment: Also, make sure disable Personal hotspot on your phone if it gets enabled

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me as well. I somehow fixed it with a reboot... go figure. I am guessing Metro Bundler was not able to launch due to port 8081 already been taken by another process. After a reboot I ran `react-native run-ios` again and this time the simulator launched properly without the error.

Mind you, this was happening to me in a brand new project.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue for iOS.

Below tricks worked for me:

- Open project in Xcode.
- Go to Product-> Scheme-> EditScheme-> Run.
- Envirionment variable Click **+** Sign.
- Add flag **`OS_ACTIVITY_MODE`** with value **`disable`**.
- Run your app from Xcode (Before this close packager.)

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error although it's same to network.

Remove the app from your device and build it again. Will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#if DEBUG
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.11.21:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
#else
#warning "PRODUCTION DEVICE"
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#endif
```

You can find your ip address from this link
https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=6526

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of the above solutions seemed to work. I tried killing the connection, reloading the bundle, stopping and running npm start again without success.
What worked for me eventually was clearing the npm cache before starting it again:

```
npm start --clear-cache
```

After this, I reloaded the bundle and the debugger was properly attached.

Answer (score 0):

Delete app from Simulator or real device and rebuild project. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me, I'm developing with my actual phone for the simulator. I had to shake my actual phone and pressed the Remote Debugging option, this loaded a new http://localhost:19001/debugger-ui/ page in my browser with an active debugger.

Answer (score 0):

1. open your `/etc/hosts`
2. check does them exist

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1       localhost
```

if not, add them and then `yarn ios` again.
if them exist, sorry, there is nothing I can do

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to mention that when you install a new app on iOS via RN, your device will ask you something about connecting with devices on WiFi, etc. I must have clicked the wrong thing and was stuck in that state. Deleting the app off of my device then re-installing (via RN) brought that dialog up where I could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I commented all lines in my /private/etc/hosts to solve some VPN issues, but it seems like for the IOS react-native debugger to attach you need these host entries:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2022:**

I was trying to run in a physical device.

1. I deleted `podfile.lock` and run `pod deintegrate`.
2. Deleted the app from physical and simulator device.
3. Checked if my phone and computer were on the same wifi.
4. Check in XCode if you are running in debug or release mode.

Then everything worked well.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i was testing ion simulator

1. open setting in simulator
2. open developer setting
3. Allow any domain turned on and it started working

Answer (score 0):

**Relaunch** Xcode and **remove** the app from device. After, **build** app again.

This is what's helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same error when wanted to use React Native Debugger with physical device. The solution for me:

1. Set a static IP for you Mac under settings -> network -> advanced -> TCP/IP -> manually and set it to like 192.168.1.85 or whatever you like
2. Shake you device to open developer menu
3. Configure bundler
4. Set the ip the same as you set in step 1, rest of the options can be left default if you haven't changed the port or something.
5. under developer menu select start Debugging remotely.

Oh and to get rid of the error in the first place, delete the app from device and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if only one remote debugger is running in your browser if there are more than the error will occur