# React native app stuck on Loading from Metro... when trying to Debug from Chrome

Tags: reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

I've had a very hard time upgrading react native version from 0.66.3 to 0.69.4. As always `npx react-native upgrade` was worthless, saying it couldn't update the files, so I have to do manually. After days of debugging, I finally was able to run the project. When I was trying to debug, I pressed the Debug with Chrome button on the device from devtools, and it froze. It just says Loading from Metro..., and nothing happens. When trying to reload from console, It just says 0/1, and immediately shows bundle in green like everything is fine. While frozen, I cannot trigger the devtools options to come up on the device. Tried flipper, but it was half working, half not, but when I saw how it displays logs (plaintext, no formatting), deleted it right away.

Is the react native support for chrome debugging removed? If not, is there a specific line/file where this issue could be possibly caused?

`package.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "format": "yarn prettier -c '**/*.+(js|json|ts|tsx|md)'",
    "format:fix": "yarn prettier --write '**/*.+(js|json|ts|tsx|md)'",
    "typecheck": "tsc --noEmit",
    "commit": "git-cz",
    "generateTypes": "graphql-codegen",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest --runInBand --detectOpenHandles --forceExit",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.6.9",
    "apollo-upload-client": "^17.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.1",
    "eventemitter3": "^4.0.7",
    "graphql": "^16.5.0",
    "graphql-ws": "^5.10.0",
    "i18next": "^21.9.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.18.3",
    "react-native": "0.69.4",
    "react-native-encrypted-storage": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.8.5",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-notification-sounds": "^0.5.4",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.4.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-native": "^5.3.3",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.11.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "victory-native": "^36.3.0",
    "ws": "^8.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.9",
    "@graphql-codegen/add": "3.2.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "2.11.6",
    "@graphql-codegen/import-types-preset": "2.2.3",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "2.7.3",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "2.5.3",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "3.3.3",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^8.0.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^4.0.11",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^11.0.0",
    "@types/apollo-upload-client": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.6",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.69.5",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.11",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.24",
    "@types/react-router-native": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.33.0",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "^0.4.4",
    "commitizen": "^4.2.5",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8.21.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.184.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "jest": "^28.1.3",
    "lint-staged": ">=13",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.72.0",
    "mockdate": "^3.0.5",
    "react-native-eject": "^0.1.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.7",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "prepare-commit-msg": "exec < /dev/tty && git cz --hook || true"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "commitizen": {
      "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

It turned out it was a network issue - which is weird because I was running it on iPad via wifi, no issues if no Debug with Chrome. On iPhone a new error message has appeared: `Connection to http://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy?role=client timed out`, and [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370916/react-native-error-connection-to-http-localhost8081-debugger-proxyrole-clie) gave the clue that it may be a network issue.

Comment: Can you attach your package.json? Otherway, are you using the Hermes engine?

Comment: @DánielBoros Not using Hermes, attached package.json to question.